# There's no Executables group in XCode Command Line Tool project?

Tags: xcode4, exc-bad-access

I create project as: File -> New -> Project and selected "Command Line Tool".

I want to use "NSZombieEnabled" to deal with exec_bad_access problem.--[LINK](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSZombieEnabled)

but i cant find the so-called "Executables group" in my project.

Answer (score 1):

OK, in XCode4 you can set "NSZombieEnabled" YES by:

```
Edit Scheme->Arguments->Environment variables
```

Hope this helpful